# Lightning card not displaying records

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am doing a simple use case of displaying a list of records from Apex controller. But I can't seem to find the reason why they are not getting displayed.

APex:

```
public with sharing class relatedOpp_Account {


    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<COntact> displayRelatedContact(string accId) {

        return [select id, name, email, accountId from contact WHERE AccountId = :accId];

        

    }
}
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import displayRelatedContact from '@salesforce/apex/relatedOpp_Account.displayRelatedContact'

export default class DisplayRelatedCon extends LightningElement {


    @api recordId;
    

    @wire(displayRelatedContact, {accId: '$recordId'})
    wiredContacts({data, error})
    {
        if(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            //console.log(this.wiredContacts(data))
            
        }
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card
        title="ApexWireMethodToProperty"
        icon-name="custom:custom63"
    >
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
          
                <template for:each={wiredContacts.data} for:item="contact">
                    <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.name}</p>
                </template>
            
            
        </div>

        
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiredContacts here is the wire method. you can't use that in the HTML file. what you would do is, create a variable in the javascript file, assign that variable all the records from the wiredContacts data and iterate that variable in the HTML in place of wiredContacts.
your code will look like-

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import displayRelatedContact from '@salesforce/apex/relatedOpp_Account.displayRelatedContact'
export default class DisplayRelatedCon extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    records;

    @wire(displayRelatedContact, {accId: '$recordId'})
    wiredContacts({data, error})
    {
        if(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            this.records=data;
        }
    }

}
```

On the HTML side-

```
<template>
    <lightning-card
        title="ApexWireMethodToProperty"
        icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
          
                <template for:each={records} for:item="contact">
                    <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.name}</p>
                </template>
            
            
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

I hope that helps